# Pyspark from S3 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm trying to get the data from s3 with pyspark from AWS EMR Cluster.
I'm still getting this error -  `An error occurred while calling o27.parquet. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/MultiObjectDeleteException.`

I have tried with different versions of jars/clusters, still no results.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.jars","/usr/lib/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar,/usr/lib/spark/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.873.jar")
sc = SparkContext( conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df2 = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3a://stackdev2prq/Badges/*")
```

I'm using hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar and aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.873.jar.
Spark 3.0.1 on Hadoop 3.2.1 YARN
I know that version I need propper version aws-java-sdk, but how can I check which version should I dounload?

Answer (score 0):

mvnrepo [provides the information](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws)

I don't see it for 3.2.1. Looking in the hadoop-project pom and JIRA versions,  [HADOOP-15642](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15642) says "1.11.375"; the move to 1.11.563 only went in with 3.2.2

do put the whole (huge) aws-java-sdk-bundle on the classpath. that shades everything and avoids version mismatch hell with jackson, httpclient etc.

That said: if you are working with EMR, you should just use the s3:// URLs and pick up the EMR team's S3 connector.